# How to share bitmap with text and url on facebook?

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0, fbsdksharedialog

> I tried different techniques but some one sharing only image on
>   facebook and some sharing only text or textwith url using SharePhoto
>   but no one sharing local image like bitmap,description and url at a
>   time.May be I am doing wrong.I am stuck from one day if any one know about it then please give
>   me some thing in details Thanks.

```
 // App code
     GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(final JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                        Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                                        try {

                                            if (isurl) {
                                                ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(mActivity);
                                                if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
                                                    ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                                                            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store?hl=en"))
                                                            .setContentDescription(message).setContentUrl(imgBitmapUri)
                                                            .build();
                                                    shareDialog.show(linkContent);
                                                }

                                            } else {
                                                SharePhoto.Builder sharePhotoBuilder = new SharePhoto.Builder();
                                                if (bitmap == null) {

                                                    sharePhotoBuilder.setBitmap(bitmap);
                                                } else {
                                                    sharePhotoBuilder.setImageUrl(Uri.parse(imgBitmapPath));
                                                }
                                                sharePhotoBuilder.setUserGenerated(false);
                                                final SharePhoto gesturePhoto = sharePhotoBuilder.build();
                                                ShareOpenGraphObject shareOpenGraphObject = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
                                                        .putString("og:type", "favorite.share")
                                                        .putString("og:description", message)
                                                        .putPhotoArrayList("og:image", new ArrayList<SharePhoto>() {{
                                                    add(gesturePhoto);
                                                        }}).build();
                                                ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
                                                        .setActionType("favorite.share")
                                                        .putObject("favorite:share", shareOpenGraphObject)
                                                        .build();
                                                ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
                                                        .setPreviewPropertyName("favorite:share").setPreviewPropertyName("image")
                                                        .setAction(action)
                                                        .build();
                                                ShareDialog.show(mActivity, content);
`enter code here`                                     }


                                            }

                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,first_name, last_name, email,link");
                        request.setParameters(parameters);
                        request.executeAsync();
```